# Appveyor different pipes build vs pr

Tags: node.js, appveyor

As AppVeyor does not pass secure env variables to PR builds. How can you split the the yml file to do different things.
Such as on a PR build I only want to run `test_scripts`. On branch on master I want it to run the `build_scripts` as to make artifacts.

I tried

```
   branches
    only:
     - master
```

but I can't seem to run build_scripts specifically there.

Basically on a merge into master I do a `yarn release` that builds the exe.  But right now a PR build it runs `test_scripts` and `build_scripts`

I'm building a Node project in appveyor specific to windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `APPVEYOR_PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER` environment variable in your script logic. For example `IF ($env:APPVEYOR_PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER)` will evaluate to `false` in non-pr build.

For a full list of built-in environment valuables please look [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/)

Comment: Hmm.. tricky not really what I was going for. Would rather split in the yml file vs the release script.

Comment: I see. Now we have that splitting only at branches level, but PR virtual merge also happens in master, so yes, you cannot use it here. By the way, do you know that you can enable secure variables in PR (for same repository only for public repo and also for any repository for private one)?

Comment: yeah, but someone could still expose the env variables in theory in the PR.